# Modeling Atomic Motion

Tags: molecular-dynamics

It seems in the molecular dynamics simulators that I've found thus far, most of them model the systems using models that treat nuclei and orbiting electrons as a single particle. At least, that's what I gathered reading about the Lennard-Jones potential on [this PDF](https://udel.edu/~arthij/MD.pdf).

Aside from the performance costs, is there any other reason why these systems can't be modeled treating the electrons and nuclei as separate particles? It seems like you could use Newtonian equations for gravity and electrical force to model bonding and van der Waals.

The downside I see from the current model is that you can't simulate electron exchanges or photon absorption/emission very well.

Comment: Most of the quantum mechanical models we use is based on the Born-Oppenheimer approximation which loosely means that the motion of the electrons and nuclei are separate, the nuclei move according to a so-called potential energy surface of the electrons. This is what MD simulations do: they treat the interaction between particles first by finding the potential between the nuclei (e.g. Lennard-Jones), then letting the nuclei evolve on this potential surface. It is certainly doable to do simulations without Born-Oppenheimer and it has been done for systems up to molecular hydrogen if I believe.

Comment: @Ezze I would take that as an answer if you post it as one. Seems like it answers my question, or at least gives me the info I was looking for.

Comment: I did not really answer your question tho. The real answer could be: MD simulations already treat electrons and nuclei separately because the vast majority of the MD methods simulate the NUCLEI moving in a pre-determined field of ELECTRONS, without coupling. Now, regarding your comment about interactions with light: non-adiabatic MD is an area of extensive research at the moment. Non-adiabatic methods kind of mean that you have multiple potential surfaces corresponding to different electronic states of the system, and you mix them in a clever way that you model absorption well.

Answer (score 1):

> Aside from the performance costs, is there any other reason why these systems can't be modeled treating the electrons and nuclei as separate particles?

Because it would produce incorrect results.

> It seems like you could use Newtonian equations for gravity and electrical force to model bonding and van der Waals.

You couldn't. You really do need to use QM to solve for the electronic eigenstates and the potential-energy surfaces that result from them.

Strictly speaking, you also need to use QM to solve for the nuclear motion, but (i) that is prohibitively expensive, and (ii) the situation is generally so complex that the interference patterns produced by QM in the nuclear motion are typically washed out, so a classical approach (i.e. Molecular Dynamics) is an excellent approximation. However, this does *not* work for electrons, for which QM is essential.

Comment: Can you expand on incorrect results?